# Is Nexus 9 capable of accessing data when I connect USB storage?

Tags: external-sd, sd-card

Info about Nexus 9:

- http://www.google.com/intl/en_uk/nexus/9/
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nexus_9
- http://www.gsmarena.com/htc_nexus_9-5823.php

---

I have no idea how latest Androids work therefore asking a pretty basic question: Will latest Android (6.0 Marshmallow) detect additional storage?

*(cannot find this info in marketing materials out there)*

Answer (score 2):

[Android Marshmallow and USB OTG Support](http://www.clintonfitch.com/2015/12/android-marshmallow-usb-otg-support/) confirms OTG working on Nexus 9 (**Note:** I have no way of verifying). Relevant extracts from the post ( missing text denoted by "....", emphasis added)

> But there is another feature that Android users have long wanted out of the platform that has come with Marshmallow: Native USB On-the-go (OTG) support...In previous released of Android, OTG support was not inherently supported and effectively required that you have your device rooted even if your hardware technically supported it.  That, it seems for Nexus devices, has gone away....  I can **confirm** that I was able to connect a **USB drive** and a mouse successfully to my Nexus 6 and Nexus 7 while I was equally able to connect both to a colleague who as the Nexus 6P and **Nexus 9**